# Sun T2000 mysteriously turning off

Tags: sun, solaris-10

We have a Sun T2000 running Solaris 10 that likes to (seemingly) randomly turn off...

We have left it hooked up to the "ser mgt" port... hoping it would report some information.  It would have the Solaris login prompt before the system would die, but after it wouldn't report any change.  However, when I push enter... it gives me the "ok>" prompt waiting for me to type "boot".

Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting?

Thanks

Comment: Anything in your logs  - `/var/adm/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: Is there a log for the SC system?

Comment: It's early and I'm being dim, what's SC?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a at least a cursory look at the hardware. Machines will sometimes power themselves off unexpectedly in response to overheating. Also suspect may be the power supply, which is certainly capable of causing the system to turn off for a number of reasons.

Comment: Well that's what I thought at first... So we changed out the chassis and still have the same issue.